# Codeigniter File Upload Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a codeigniter application which basically accepts `xls` files, parse it and process on the data from the excel file.

Here is the code that I used for uploading the file.

When the form is submitted, the code below is executed. When I submit a file with small size, it is uploaded properly and is also processed. However, if I upload a file with a larger size, it gets uploaded, but isnt processed. I even get redirected to the upload form with the error **"You did not select a file to upload."**

Is this something which is caused by `max_execution_time`?
PS: I have these three lines at the top of the controller

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

**UPDATE :**
The file size I am trying to update is of 1.59 MB

**Upload**

```
public function do_upload() {
     $config['upload_path']   = './excel_files/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
     $config['max_size']      = 100000;

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    //  upload failed, handle properly
     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data = array('subview'=>'admin/upload_form','error'=>$error);
        $this->load->view('layout', $data);
     }

    //  upload success, record the file data
     else {
       $uploadData = $this->upload->data();

       $fileData = array(
                      'name'    =>  $uploadData['orig_name'],
                      'size'    =>  $uploadData['file_size'],
                      'stored_name' =>  $uploadData['file_name'],
       );

       $this->file_m->insert($fileData);

        $this->process($uploadData); // process the uploaded  file
     }
  }
```

Comment: have you used enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag

Comment: @AmitGaud files with smaller size get uploaded. So it is quite obvious that the form uses `multipart/form-data`

Comment: is your filesize is greater then $config['max_size']  = 100000; KB ?

Comment: @VasimPadhiyar it is of 1.59 MB

Comment: what is your file size

Comment: Please check     upload_max_filesize and post_max_size value in php configuration. If it has lower value then please increase and try again.

Comment: Have you checked upload_max_filesize & post_max_size php.ini settings value ?

Comment: @prakashchhetri  please share HTML code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks overriding code is not working.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

**Way 1:**

Update the settings in php.ini file. Hope issue will be resolved.

```
max_execution_time = 259200
max_input_time = 259200
memory_limit = 300M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
```

**Way 2:**

`.htaccess` way

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

verify the settings by creating a php info file.
`test_settings.php`

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function upload_it() {
    //load the helper
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads/';

    // set the filter image types
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';

    //load the upload library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

    $data['upload_data'] = '';

    //if not successful, set the error message
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
      $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    } else { //else, set the success message
      $data = array('msg' => "Upload success!");

      $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();

    }

    //load the view/upload.php
    $this->load->view('upload', $data);

  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.